# Magento2: how to delete summary field from review form

Tags: magento2, review

I want delete filed **Summary** from reviews product form.

In file `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml`

I comment line:

```
<div class="field review-field-summary required">
    <label for="summary_field" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Summary')) ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="title" id="summary_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}" data-bind="value: review().title" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently, the "Summary" field is not displayed. But when trying to add reviews, I get an error that I need to fill this field. How to solve it?

I try delete this filed from reviews form:
https://prnt.sc/o2v4w0

I delete this in `form.html` and now not displayed:
https://prnt.sc/o2v56q

But when I try add review:
https://prnt.sc/o2v5kl
Then error because system still required this field.

Comment: Can you take a screenhot of that error and add it your question?

Comment: I edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by creating a module with name STech_Review by following steps:

**Step 1:** Create **Registration.php** under

> app/code/STech/Review/registration.php

with content

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Review',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:** Create **module.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Review/etc/module.xml

with content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Review" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Review"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:** Create **di.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Review/etc/di.xml

with content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Review\Model\Review" type="STech\Review\Model\Review"/>
</config>
```

**Step 4:** Create **Review.php** under

> app/code/STech/Review/Model/Review.php

with content

```
<?php
namespace STech\Review\Model;

class Review extends \Magento\Review\Model\Review
{
    public function validate()
    {
        $errors = [];

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getNickname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter a nickname.');
        }

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getDetail(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter a review.');
        }

        if (empty($errors)) {
            return true;
        }
        return $errors;
    }
}
```

Finally you need to alter the table review_details by changing field title to optional(Nullable true).

Thats it. Run setup:upgrade, di:compile and other required commands and test.

Comment: Ok but this magento module is located at: vendor/magento/module-review/ not in app/code.

Comment: Yes I am asking you to create own module and override in this way.

Comment: Are you getting my point?

Comment: I add this code in app/code after setup:upgrade and deploy no result. Still required this field

Comment: Did you create complete module? Or only added these codes?

Comment: I just added this code. I think that creating the whole module is too advanced for me today

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95007/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-sylvester).

Comment: Did you find the table?

Comment: Unfortunately. The search engine in phpmyadmin finds all tables for me. But I can not find this table; ( review_

Comment: Can you share the screenhot in the chat room?

Comment: The best answer I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a default value for summary in your controller file before saving review. This is mandatory field in review model. Else you can modify models to make it non-mandatory. Best way to set some default value so that it get saved but we can manage the output at frontend.

Comment: in which file controlller is located this file?

Answer (score 0):

Magento validates for the required fields of the review form in the **/vendor/magento/module-review/Model/Review.php** file.

First, you need to override this file. To do so, create a file **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml** and write the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Review\Model\Review" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Review"/>
</config>
```

Next, create the Model file **app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Review.php** and put the following code in this file:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Review extends \Magento\Review\Model\Review
{
    public function validate()
    {
        $errors = [];

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getNickname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter a nickname.');
        }

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getDetail(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter a review.');
        }

        if (empty($errors)) {
            return true;
        }
        return $errors;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I assume that you know how to create a basic module in Magento 2.

Comment: Is there an updated version of this for magento 2.4.6 where the zend validate doesn't exist?